# Create a wordpress blog appear like this: www.allwomenstalk.com

Tags: css, wordpress, blogs

I have no experience with Wordpress template designing so far, and this will be my first attempt on it. I'm assuming that it will be pretty much the same as other CMS's, but if there are any special instructions that you think are important, I will be more than grateful.

As for the question, I want my posts to appear in the same manner as the website below:
http://allwomenstalk.com/

The easiest way I thought was to float all the container DIV's to the left, but that will not cater for the varying heights of the container. Any tips or ideas?

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a lot of work asked in a simple question. Try this jQuery plugin to get you started on that kind of layout:

http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/basic-single-column.html

Comment: Is this a cross-browser solution?

Comment: @salmanhijazi latest version should support IE7+, everything else is good.

Answer (score 0):

The website linked to is using inline-styles to specify an `absolute` position, with varying `left` indents.